# Lo-dash extend/assign default behavior

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to understand the assign/extend functions in lodash as I bumped into a very confusing result going trough the mean.io stack setup.

Here:

```
'use strict';

var _ = require('lodash');

// Load app configuration
var foo = require(__dirname + '/../config/env/all.js');
console.log('-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-. foo before _.assign .-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-');
console.log(foo)

module.exports = _.assign(
    require(__dirname + '/../config/env/all.js'),
    require(__dirname + '/../config/env/' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.js') || {}
    );

var bar = require(__dirname + '/../config/env/all.js');

console.log('-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-. foo after _.assign .-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-');
console.log(foo);
console.log('-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-. bar .-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-');
console.log(bar);
console.log('-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-. A direct require call .-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-');
console.log(require(__dirname + '/../config/env/all.js'));
```

And what I'm getting is:

```
-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-. foo before _.assign .-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-
{ root: '/home/bax/Code/lab/mean/test1',
  port: 3000,
  db: undefined }
-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-. foo after _.assign .-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-
{ root: '/home/bax/Code/lab/mean/test1',
  port: 3000,
  db: 'mongodb://localhost/mean-dev',
  app: { name: 'MEAN - A Modern Stack - Development' },
  facebook: 
   { clientID: 'APP_ID',
     clientSecret: 'APP_SECRET',
     callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback' },
  twitter: 
   { clientID: 'CONSUMER_KEY',
     clientSecret: 'CONSUMER_SECRET',
     callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter/callback' },
  github: 
   { clientID: 'APP_ID',
     clientSecret: 'APP_SECRET',
     callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/github/callback' },
  google: 
   { clientID: 'APP_ID',
     clientSecret: 'APP_SECRET',
     callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback' } }
-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-. bar .-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-
{ root: '/home/bax/Code/lab/mean/test1',
  port: 3000,
  db: 'mongodb://localhost/mean-dev',
  app: { name: 'MEAN - A Modern Stack - Development' },
  facebook: 
   { clientID: 'APP_ID',
     clientSecret: 'APP_SECRET',
     callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback' },
  twitter: 
   { clientID: 'CONSUMER_KEY',
     clientSecret: 'CONSUMER_SECRET',
     callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter/callback' },
  github: 
   { clientID: 'APP_ID',
     clientSecret: 'APP_SECRET',
     callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/github/callback' },
  google: 
   { clientID: 'APP_ID',
     clientSecret: 'APP_SECRET',
     callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback' } }
-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-. A direct require call .-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-
{ root: '/home/bax/Code/lab/mean/test1',
  port: 3000,
  db: 'mongodb://localhost/mean-dev',
  app: { name: 'MEAN - A Modern Stack - Development' },
  facebook: 
   { clientID: 'APP_ID',
     clientSecret: 'APP_SECRET',
     callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback' },
  twitter: 
   { clientID: 'CONSUMER_KEY',
     clientSecret: 'CONSUMER_SECRET',
     callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter/callback' },
  github: 
   { clientID: 'APP_ID',
     clientSecret: 'APP_SECRET',
     callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/github/callback' },
  google: 
   { clientID: 'APP_ID',
     clientSecret: 'APP_SECRET',
     callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback' } }
Express app started on port 3000
```

The question is: Am I not supposed to get the same results every time I do: `console.log(require(__dirname + '/../config/env/all.js'));`?

Comment: You're getting the same object but you have modified it in between?

Comment: Uhmm, ohh. I think I get it. What I get from require() is a reference to the module.exports object which is modified by _.assign(), so when I call require() again I get a reference to that same modified module exports object ... is this right?

Comment: Thank you! It was not really clear to me at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered in the comments already, but here's an attempt on a more qualified answer and to close this topic:

The effect you're getting is due to combined effect of node.js module loading and lodash _.extend():

- Included modules are just objects and they are cached, so every subsequent call to 'require()' relating to the same physical file system path will return that object
- Lodash's extend/assign is annoyingly destructive, it's manipulates the passed object directly instead of returning a new object (like e.g. Rubys 'Hash#merge()' would do)

So you have one object representing `all.js` and `_.assign()` manipulates that. Any further `require()`'s will just return the same, modified object.

If this is undesired (and in many situations it is), only workaround I know of so far is this:

```
var someOptions = {/*...*/};
var extended = _.extend(_.clone(someOptions))
```